# How to add lines after pattern by ansible playbook

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, centos

I have file name test

```
[tag1]
[tag2]
```

I want to add lines after [tag1] in test I find this solution

```
  - name: Add content
    lineinfile:
      path: test
      insertafter: '[tag1]'
      line: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - '# This is line 1'
      - '# This is line 2'
      - '# This is line 3'
```

But it add those line at the end of file not after [tag1]
And If I run playbook twice it added it 2 times I want to check if those lines are not exist after [tag1] add them and if exist do nothing.

What should I do?
Why it added lines at the end of file?

Answer (score 2):

[lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html#lineinfile-manage-lines-in-text-files) is not consistent. See [lineinfile is not idempotent #58923](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/58923).

> This is caused by a bug in the logic around firstmatch. This bug is present in devel all the way back to Ansible 2.5 ...

In the task below

```
- lineinfile:
    path: test
    insertafter: '[tag1]'
    firstmatch: yes
    line: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - '# This is line 1'
```

the parameter `firstmatch: yes` helps to put the `line` before `[tag2]`

```
$ cat test
[tag1]
# This is line 1
[tag2]
```

, but when the play is repeated the same parameter causes the `line` to be added repeatedly. (Feel free to try.)

Use [ini_file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ini_file_module.html#ini-file-tweak-settings-in-ini-files) instead. The task below

```
- ini_file:
    path: test
    section: "{{ item.section }}"
    option: "{{ item.option }}"
    allow_no_value: yes
  loop:
    - section: 'tag1'
      option: '# This is line 1'
    - section: 'tag1'
      option: '# This is line 2'
```

gives the idempotent result.

```
$ cat test
[tag1]
# This is line 2
# This is line 1
[tag2]
```

Comment: How I prevent to add line repeatedly if I run playbook mutiple time. I want to check if the line exist do not add them

Comment: You'll better off using template, blockinfile, and ini_file [modules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_files_modules.html#files-modules). Use `lineinfile` in very simple cases as the last option. Especially when there are tags in the file use ini_file.

Comment: I do not understand how to check if the line exist how can I control it by ini_file.would you pleas give me an example?

Comment: Sure. Why do you want to know whether a line is present in a file before you run the play? Is it important? No. It is important what lines will be present in the file after the play completes. This is Ansible philosophy, to define the state of a system.  To insert multiple lines just add the items into the loop. See [example](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-freebsd-postinstall/blob/master/tasks/devfs.yml).

Comment: I want to run playbook multiple and I want to be sure not adding one line multiple time

Comment: If you have problems follow [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: This what I asked in this question